# Trying to evaluate order after a shuffle - JSFiddle included

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, shuffle

I'm shuffling the items in a row in a table using a basic shuffle function:

```
var ratings = ['rating0','rating1','rating2','rating3'];

var shuffle = function(arr) {
    for(var j, x, i = arr.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = arr[--i], arr[i] = arr[j], arr[j] = x);
    return arr;
}
shuffle(ratings);

$("#rating0").html(ratings[0]);
$("#rating1").html(ratings[1]);
$("#rating2").html(ratings[2]);
$("#rating3").html(ratings[3]);
$("#rating4").html(ratings[4]);
```

The ratings then appear as entries in a row within a table:

```
<table>         
    <tr id="ColumnLabels">
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
         <td>Column 3</td>
          <td>Column 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id = "rating1"></td>
        <td id = "rating0"></td>
        <td id = "rating2"></td>
         <td id = "rating3"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As illustrated in the following JSFiddle, I'd like to evaluate the order of the items after the shuffle to identify the column under which Rating1 appears:  http://jsfiddle.net/HT89v/38/

I tried playing around with `.parent().hasClass` to determine the post-shuffle location of each item (http://jsfiddle.net/HT89v/48/):

```
   <tr>
        <span class="column1"><td id = "rating1"></td></span>
        <span class="column2"><td id = "rating0"></td></span>
        <span class="column3"><td id = "rating2"></td></span>
         <span class="column4"><td id = "rating3"></td></span>
    </tr>
```

---

```
$(function () {
    if ($('#rating1').parent().hasClass('column1')) {
        alert('column1');
    }
});
```

I figure that the `<td>` will shuffle but each `<span>` will remain in the same place, which would allow me to identify the post-shuffle location; however, this does not seem to work.

I'd greatly appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Comment: Your code doesn't shuffle the TDs, it just changes their text.

Comment: You can't have `<span>` as a child of `<tr>`. It has to be `<tr> <td> <span>...</span> </td> </tr>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working sample of what you need.(But I strongly suggest to change your code towards a better design)

```js
var ratings = ['rating0','rating1','rating2','rating3'];


var shuffle = function(arr) {
    for(var j, x, i = arr.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = arr[--i], arr[i] = arr[j], arr[j] = x);
    return arr;
}
shuffle(ratings);
//ratings[4] = Math.round(Math.random() * 3) + 7;



$("#rating0").html(ratings[0]);
$("#rating1").html(ratings[1]);
$("#rating2").html(ratings[2]);
$("#rating3").html(ratings[3]);

$(function () {
    $("#rowRatings").find('td.ratings').each(function(index) {
      if($(this).text()=="rating1")
      {
       //Result would be the column name that has same index as that of the one with value "rating1"
       $("#result").text($('#ColumnLabels td:nth-child('+ (index+1)+')').text());
        
      }
    });      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
"rating1" is under <span id="result"></span>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<table>   
    <tr id="ColumnLabels">
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
         <td>Column 3</td>
          <td>Column 4</td>
          
    </tr>
    <tr id="rowRatings">
        <td id = "rating0" class="ratings"></td>
        <td id = "rating1" class="ratings"></td>
        <td id = "rating2" class="ratings"></td>
        <td id = "rating3" class="ratings"></td>        
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Jeshwel! This is so helpful. Just to make sure I understand this correctly: `each(function(index)` essentially "stores" the index for every element in the set `td.ratings`, right? Why do we have to add 1 in this part of the code: `+ (index+1)+`? Wouldn't the index of the corresponding column be the same as the index of the row? (I apologize for these likely naive questions, but this is really helping me learn.) Thanks!

Comment: .each() is just like for loop, it iterates through each element starting with index as 0, but in css to get first element you have to give td:nth-child(1). Check this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-child